# need to find winows.storage NuGet package in MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui

When I implement I need to add some packages in MAUI C# .
using Windows.Storage;

[image]
I couldn't find the package. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the top left of your screenshot you will see that this file is targeting Android. This means that either this file is very specific to Android *or* it can be built for multiple platforms including Android.

If we then look at your code and your question: you're trying to add very Windows specific code and packages to code that is supposed to run on Android (as well as maybe iOS & macOS). This will never work.

Your questions has not enough detail to provide you with a full answer but it seems like you're trying to save a file. What you probably want to do is follow the .NET MAUI documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/invoke-platform-code?view=net-maui-7.0), for implementing platform-specific code.

Each platform has a very specific, but also very different filesystem. A simple example of what you are trying to do and why it won't work: imagine that we *could* install this functionality on our app and calling `SaveFile` will try to save something to `C:\MyFolder\MyFile.csv`. On Android and iOS, there is no such concept of accessing the filesystem through `C:\`.

Therefore, to implement similar functionality for each platform you will need to implement a slightly different approach to get there. Hopefully this clears that up a little bit.